# How to unit test RxJava retryWhen

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to use an exponential backoff with RxJava Completable and the code works fine when I try it. So was trying to add a unit test to cover it but am not sure how we can test the `retryWhen` part here.

```
    fun makeCall(
        scheduler: Scheduler = scheduler.io()
    ) : Completable {
        val value = "myString"

        return myCompletable(value)
            .retryWhen { errors: Flowable<Throwable> ->
                errors
                    .zipWith(Flowable.range(1, 3))
                    .flatMap { errorRetryPair: Pair<Throwable, Int> ->
                        Flowable.timer(2.toDouble().pow(errorRetryPair.second.toDouble()).toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    }
            }.subscribeOn(scheduler)
    }
```

does anyone know how we can test this? (haven't been able to find much info about testing to make sure the retryWhen works)

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing RxJava timed operations is best done with a `TestScheduler`.

```
// in your test code
simulateFailure();
long firstStepMs = 2_000; // first backoff time in ms
long epsilon = 40;        // 10ms is too small
scheduler.advanceTimeBy( firstStepMs - epsilon, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
// test to see that resubscription has NOT occurred
scheduler.advanceTimeBy( 2 * epsilon, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
// test to see that first resubscription HAS occurred
```

and repeat for different back off times. The granularity of advancing the clock is up to you. `epsilon` **must** be larger than 10 milliseconds because of how timer scheduling in Java works; you certainly won't be able to usefully measure any shorter intervals.

Comment: thanks! would be very helpful if you could add an example of how to "test the resubscription"

Comment: If your observer chain does not perform an externally visible operation when you re-subscribe, you can temporarily add `doOnSubscribe()` operator to the chain, above the `retryWhen()` operator. Have it increment a counter or something and just check the value. Normally, you wouldn't be unit testing your backoff algorithm on real connections, and should extract that portion into a test harness.

Comment: yeah have done the manually testing and verifying that it works as expected (as mentioned in my post), and am now looking to see if this can be unit test with a scheduler now?

Comment: In a unit test, you want your test harness to be controlled by the testing code. In your case, you want the `Completable` at the start of your observer chain to be controlled and instrumented. For instance, you can use `Completable.create()` to make a completable that will record subscriptions and allow you to trigger errors.